# Get Android gradle plugin & checkstyle working together / command line usage

Tags: android, gradle, checkstyle

I'm evaluating the ability of the new gradle-based build system to reproduce our current ant-based build process and, as a gradle beginner, I failed to get checkstyle running with the android gradle plugin.

*Environment:*

- gradle 1.6 running fine on a standard java project (checkstyle check target included)
- up-to-date android SDK (22.0.1 with platform tools and build tools 17)
- no eclipse, no android studio, only my lovely terminal

*Symptom:*

The target project is https://github.com/nibua-r/LigoTextDemo and I succeeded to build it using gradle but if I naively add `apply plugin: checkstyle` to my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

android {
  buildToolsVersion '17'
  compileSdkVersion 15
  testBuildType 'debug'

  defaultConfig {
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = '1.0'
    minSdkVersion 12
    targetSdkVersion 15
  }

  buildTypes {
    debug {
      packageNameSuffix = '.debug'
    }
  }
}
```

then `gradle check` doesn't even complain on not finding the `checkstyle.xml` file (at the default `config/checkstyle` location) and returns:

```
:check UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

*What's needed:*

First, I just need a running checkstyle target. Then, I need to automate checkstyle running as a dependency of the compilation (but lets get the chekstyle target up and running first).

*Assumption:*

This may be related to the fact that (from the [user guide][1]):

> The Android plugin […] uses its own sourceSets

but I'm not enough gradle-efficient to understand what I'm missing there. Please, gradle Master, enlighten me with your valuable knowledge!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found by digging on the web that the Android plugin depends on java-base and not java (i.e. the sourceSets management is specific) and the checkstyle plugin rely on java. As a consequence, some gradle upstream modification are needed to get the thing done. The gradle team is working on that, as seen on twitter:

[@anzix](https://twitter.com/anzix) Android source sets will be soon understood by the generic code quality plugins. Work on that has already started.

— Gradle Build System (@Gradleware) [May 26, 2013](https://twitter.com/Gradleware/statuses/338786348607610880)

Comment: Thank you very much for this update. Do you know if there is web page somewhere to get updated of the status of the work on Android ? I am not that much a tweeter follower.

Answer (score 30):

I got pmd, findbugs, and checkstyle working with Gradle 1.12 android plugin 0.12.+ using the following script:

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
apply plugin: 'pmd'

check.dependsOn 'checkstyle', 'findbugs', 'pmd'

task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
    configFile file("${project.rootDir}/config/quality/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml")
    source 'src'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/gen/**'

    classpath = files()
}

task findbugs(type: FindBugs) {
    ignoreFailures = true
    effort = "max"
    reportLevel = "high"
    excludeFilter = new File("${project.rootDir}/config/quality/findbugs/findbugs-filter.xml")
    classes = files("$project.buildDir/intermediates/classes/")

    source 'src'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/gen/**'

    reports {
        xml {
            destination "$project.buildDir/reports/findbugs/findbugs.xml"
            xml.withMessages true
        }
    }

    classpath = files()
}

task pmd(type: Pmd) {
    ruleSetFiles = files("${project.rootDir}/config/quality/pmd/pmd-ruleset.xml")
    ignoreFailures = true
    ruleSets = ["basic", "braces", "strings"]

    source 'src'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/gen/**'

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = false
    }
}
```

Running `gradle build` in command line will run all code quality plugins and generate xml reports in **app/build/reports/** which are then ready to be viewed or parsed by CI tools.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Can you please edit your post to describe your workflow? What do you do once the reports are generated?

Comment: I took the time to update the repo and script to reflect the changes made in Android Plugin 0.12.+. At my company, once the reports are generated we use Jenkins plugins to display a graph per report.

Comment: The PMD plug-in that comes with Gradle 2+ by default requires a slightly different `ruleSets` array in the `pmd` task: `ruleSets = ["java-basic", "java-braces", "java-strings"]`

Comment: the checkstyle config directory can be defined as `configProperties.checkstyleConfigDir = new File("${project.rootDir}/config/quality”, 'checkstyle’)`, which is useful for specifying checkstyle suppressions in checkstyle.xml `<module name="SuppressionFilter"><property name="file" value="${checkstyleConfigDir}/checkstyle-suppressions.xml" /></module>`

Comment: Can you explain why you have to set classpath to empty file:     `classpath = files()` ?

Answer (score 7):

Someone has a great answer to solve integrating PMD, findbugs and checkstyle with Gradle for Android.
Unfortunately, the only solution for now is based on ant : 
http://sethrylan.org/2013/07/14/gradle-android-findbugs.html

I wish gradle will one day allow to do as much as maven for Android.

--- Update as of October 2013

With Gradle 1.8 and Android plugin for Gradle 0.6.+, you don't need this anymore. Android sourcesets and configurations are now compatible with the java plugin and all quality plugin work out of the box.

This includes pmd, findbugs, checkstyle and classycle.

--- Update 
A configuration, largely inspired from the project mentioned above, is proposed in [this open source project](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/Quality-Tools-for-Android) as well, plus other tools.

Comment: Can you explain exactly how to add it to Gradle file after October 2013 (I am mainly interested in checkstyle)? Thank you

Comment: Follow the last link with Quality Tools for Android. You will find some sample configuration.

Comment: "With Gradle 1.8 and Android plugin for Gradle 0.6.+, you don't need this anymore. Android sourcesets and configurations are now compatible with the java plugin and all quality plugin work out of the box." Is this correct? With those versions, I have no checkstyle task after applying the plugin.

Comment: @ZoFex, yes this should work. Here you can find an other example :https://bitbucket.org/saibotd/bitbeaker/src/82ccdd3c40a898e55cd9752daeab0b3fc53c3810/build.gradle?at=default

Comment: The linked example is clearly specifying which Java classes to include with no regard at all to source sets. I only get a "checkstyle" task - no "checkstyleDebug" etc tasks, and running checkstyle returns issues from all source sets including tests.

Comment: I get an error saying "Could not normalize path for file... File name too long" using the Quality Tools for Android configuration when I set up the findbugs plugin. Im using Gradle 1.11 and android plugin version 0.9.+

Answer (score 5):

To get this to work with my Android project, I had to declare the task explicitly.

Here's what worked for me:

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
    source 'src'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/gen/**'

    // empty classpath
    classpath = files()
}
```

Be mindful that the Android plugin may choose to create a task of the same name in the future or work in conjunction with the checkstyle plugin in different ways.

Comment: Could you precise what versions of gradle and of the android gradle plugin are used?

Comment: At least this works with gradle 0.6.1 and gradle 1.8

Answer (score 5):

You can try Android Check plugin (https://github.com/noveogroup/android-check):

- Checkstyle
- PMD

Configuration:

```
buildscript {
    repositories { jcenter() }
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.noveogroup.android:check:+'
        ...
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.noveogroup.android.check'
```

You can use hardcore configuration:

```
check {
    abortOnError true
    checkstyle { config hard() }
    pmd { config hard() }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Soter](https://github.com/dlabs/soter) Gradle plugin to semlessly add support for Findbugs, Checkstyle and PMD to Android projects.